# MySql count of group by result

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get records based on applied search criteria. At a time I'm only selecting 50 rows(for pagination of the table used on webpage). But I also need the `total` number of rows that satisfies the search criteria (to show `1-50 out of <total> records` & so on).

Following query gives me records group by userid.

```
select * from user 
group by userid
where name like '%hhh%' 
limit 50 offset 0
```

Here I'll will get first 50 records that satisfies the criteria, but total search results can be greater than 50. I need this total count along with other query result.

Comment: what for do you need the group by? I guess userid is the primary key, so it should be unique...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a separate query:

```
select count(*) from user
group by userid
where name like '%hhh%'
```

Your query will be much quicker and can be run each time another 50 rows are selected, then you can run this longer running query once, to get the total

Answer (score 0):

try this query..

```
select count(*) as total,userid from users
where name like '%hhh%' 
 group by userid limit 50 offset 0
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports this with the [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) option. Something like the following: (adapted (but untested!) from the docs):

```
mysql> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM user
-> WHERE name like '%hhh%' LIMIT 50;
mysql> SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```